# Peperomia obtusifolia, brown spots on all leaves

Tags: diagnosis

I would need your need to better understand what's wrong with my Peperomia plant.

To give a bit of background: I bought the plant 2 months and everything was going smoothly. Three weeks ago i went on holiday for 1 week and I have used some sort of 'irrigation system' that was supposed to give water in a controlled way -- of course it didn't work and all my plants were over-watered.
Secondly, after coming back I saw some small black insects in the plant and I thought that they could be aphids, sucking sap from the leaves. I already sprayed a solution of water and soap and I haven't seen any more insects (at least alive and moving).

Today, the plant has brown spots all over and two/three leaves have fallen. I have checked the roots and they seem fine and not rotten.

Any idea on what I can do?
[image: First photo]

[image: Leaf detail]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the unhappy plant and the black flies are separate but related problems. The black insects could well be [fungus gnats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus_gnat) - these can occur in overwatering situations since they love to breed where there is lots of water at the surface of the soil where roots are rotting due to excess moisture. Compare what you see to the available images to see if this is correct. The fungus gnats will not be interested in the leaves.

The black areas of the leaves will also be due to excess water. Peperomia likes moist conditions but the roots have to be able to breathe, which calls for lots of air in the root ball. Leaves, once established, cannot be maintained when the root volume shuts down, and this will cause parts of the leaves to die off.

Action at this point is to cut back on the water to keep the roots moist but not wet, and to remove the worst of the black leaves. Keeping the surface on the dry side will discourage the gnats. Removing some leaves will rebalance the top growth with the available root volume and may allow the plant to recover.